# $resource URL with in-path parameter

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-resource

I have the following method in a service:

```
function getMyData() {
    if (service.myData === NULL) {
        service.myData = $resource(API.MY_DATA, {}).query();
    }
    return service.myData;
}
```

`API.MY_DATA` = `'/path1/path2/path3/:myparam'`

`:myparam` parameter will be an integer representing an id that the back-end will need to use in order to perform the appropriate query to return what is being requested by a GET request.

Question:  How do I pass this parameter in my `getMyData` method appropriately so it resolves to something like:

`/path1/path2/path3/568`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getMyData() {
   if (service.myData === NULL) {
       var api = $resource(API.MY_DATA, {}); 
       service.myData = api.query({'myparam', value}); 
   }
   return service.myData;
 }
```

I would suggest you to create a factory so then you can reuse the service instead of recreate every time you need to use it. This way you only need to inject the factory/service.

```
.factory("apiService", ['$resource', function($resource){
  return $resource( url, null, {extra api call if need}); 
}
```